# HTML Div is distrorting the page after disabling it

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

[image]I am trying to disable div on a value change but when i disable it then distort the alignment.
Here is my div code :

```
<div class="col-2 col-xl-3 m-2">
<div visible='<%#Eval("ComIndicator").ToString().Trim() != "I" ?true : false %>' class="medium">Issue Date: <%# Eval("IssueDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %></div>
</div>
```

With Div field
Hidden Div field

[image: snapshots]

Comment: first the `runat=server` is not exist on div... second you need to check if some div is inside here that belong to other div out side - need to see the final html code to locate the error

Comment: no Div is inside of this Div...but this is inside on another Div.......like <Div> <div visible='<%#Eval("ComIndicator").ToString().Trim() != "I" ?true : false %>' class="medium">Issue Date: <%# Eval("IssueDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %></div>
</Div>

Comment: @Aristos my this Div comes under <div class="col-2 col-xl-3 m-2"></Div>